# Bringing Feature Selection To Top using ArcObjects?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, arcgis-engine

I'm using IFeatureSelection.SelectFeatures() to select parcel polygons in my parcel layer.

It works fine until I create a ClassBreaksRenderer to apply a color ramp based on a field in the feature.

The selection proceeds without error but does not draw on top of the renderer.

Is there a way to ensure that the feature selection draws on top?

Answer (score 1):

Try calling [`IActiveView.PartialRefresh`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//0012000001nm000000), passing in the `esriViewGeoSelection` draw phase -- once before, and once after selecting the features.

Comment: I can select an area correctly and then apply the renderer and the area remains selected. In addition I have discovered that the only the UniqueRenderer completely prevents the selection.  The ClassBreaksRenderer works correctly (with the PartialRefresh) for some of the selection - but not all!
For example: in one case the SelectionSet said that the SelectFeatures() query returned 11 and the map only selected 8!

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to is with IScreenDisplay.Invalidate, see code [here](http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=993&t=100353&g=1#281066).

Comment: Tried this also and it failed. Could this be a real bug?  The fact that it works randomly is disturbing? Does anyone know how to track the ArcGIS bugs - is there a site where they are listed?

Comment: @chaz I've seen random draw bugs in situations where there's an exception after IDisplay.StartDrawing but before IDisplay.FinishDrawing is called.  In this situation the screen caches get into an unstable state  I wonder if somehow the renderer has an unhandled exception internally.  Are you using a custom renderer anywhere?

Comment: No custom renderer, just classbreaks and unique but I have been curious about the "NullReferenceExceptions" I see in the output window while I'm running the program - but this happens with no renderers defined. (And I have tried to track down everything that needed to be released.)

Comment: Have you run in debug mode after setting Debug>Exceptions> and check CLR and C++ for thrown exceptions?

Comment: Thanks! Found out was was causing the null reference exception (Enabled is called without class instantiation?) 

But I still can't do a select on top of a classified layer.